# Twitter Search by Hastag missing parameters?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I am using the below call to Twitter API

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#iosgames
```

I get the response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":25,"message":"Query parameters are missing."}]}
```

According the [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) the only parameter that is required is `q` for the query string.

The issue isn't with my OAuth as it fine with the status/user calls.

What am I missing?

Comment: The pound sign (hash tag) needs to be encoded, I believe.

Comment: Bloody well done. %23 fixed it.

Comment: Neat, glad I could help. Answer is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pound sign (or hash sign, if you prefer) is one of those which must be encoded in order to be sent in a URL. `#` is represented by `%23`, so your request should be for:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23iosgames
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to url-encode your hashtag:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23iosgames`

[Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)